# Twilio Client Android v1.2.8 crashes when client device make call and onDisconnected method of ConnectionListener is not called automatically

Tags: android, twilio

I'm building BasicPhone Sample app of Twilio Client Android v1.2.8 in Android Studio.
I tested this app in Android 6.0 and Android 4.0.4 client.
When I pressed "CALL" button in app, Logcat frequently traced following error and app crashed.

```
12-10 01:37:51.821 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: 

art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xff
12-10 01:37:51.821 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     string: '192.168.10.113��'
12-10 01:37:51.821 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     in call to NewStringUTF
12-10 01:37:51.821 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     from void com.twilio.client.impl.useragent.Call.makeCall(com.twilio.client.impl.session.Account, java.lang.String, com.twilio.client.impl.useragent.MessageData)
12-10 01:37:51.821 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] "Thread-3151" prio=5 tid=18 Runnable
12-10 01:37:51.821 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12d64ee0 self=0xf3c03400
12-10 01:37:51.821 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | sysTid=1057 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xe070f930
12-10 01:37:51.821 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | state=R schedstat=( 41721822 17490781 146 ) utm=1 stm=3 core=4 HZ=100
12-10 01:37:51.821 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | stack=0xe060d000-0xe060f000 stackSize=1038KB
12-10 01:37:51.821 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
12-10 01:37:51.821 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #00 pc 0035a217  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+126)
12-10 01:37:51.821 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #01 pc 0033b03b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+138)
12-10 01:37:51.821 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #02 pc 0024df6b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+750)
12-10 01:37:51.821 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #03 pc 0024e60f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortV(char const*, char const*, std::__va_list)+54)
12-10 01:37:51.822 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #04 pc 000fbbfd  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::AbortF(char const*, ...)+28)
12-10 01:37:51.822 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #05 pc 001015c7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::Check(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, bool, char const*, art::JniValueType*) (.constprop.95)+7906)
12-10 01:37:51.822 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #06 pc 0010814b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::NewStringUTF(_JNIEnv*, char const*)+366)
12-10 01:37:51.822 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #07 pc 00046b97  /data/app/com.twilio.example.basicphone-2/lib/arm/libtwilio-native.so (???)
12-10 01:37:51.822 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #08 pc 00046be3  /data/app/com.twilio.example.basicphone-2/lib/arm/libtwilio-native.so (???)
12-10 01:37:51.822 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #09 pc 00058781  /data/app/com.twilio.example.basicphone-2/lib/arm/libtwilio-native.so (???)
12-10 01:37:51.822 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #10 pc 0004fc8f  /data/app/com.twilio.example.basicphone-2/lib/arm/libtwilio-native.so (???)
12-10 01:37:51.822 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #11 pc 0005010b  /data/app/com.twilio.example.basicphone-2/lib/arm/libtwilio-native.so (???)
12-10 01:37:51.822 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #12 pc 00045897  /data/app/com.twilio.example.basicphone-2/lib/arm/libtwilio-native.so (Java_com_twilio_client_impl_useragent_Call_makeCall+138)
12-10 01:37:51.822 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #13 pc 000225dd  /data/app/com.twilio.example.basicphone-2/oat/arm/base.odex (void com.twilio.client.impl.useragent.Call.makeCall(com.twilio.client.impl.session.Account, java.lang.String, com.twilio.client.impl.useragent.MessageData)+144)
12-10 01:37:51.822 997-1057/com.twilio.example.basicphone A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #14 pc 00021997  /data/app/com.twilio.example.basicphone-2/oat/arm/base.odex (void com.twilio.client.impl.useragent.Call.<init>(com.twilio.client.impl.session.Account, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, com.twilio.client.impl.useragent.MessageData)+178)
.
.
.
```

And, I make call to Inbound client,  Inbound client shows AlertDialog to respond, then I pressed "IN PROGRESS" button in Outbound client to disconnect, but onDisconnected method of ConnectionListener in BasicPhone.java is not called automatically from Twilio Client Android v1.2.7.

I also tested BasicPhone Sample app in Twilio Client Android v1.2.6, I did not encounter above probrems.

Does anyone know how to solve above problems or are those problems bugs in libraries?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue and this is in fact an issue with the library. I have reported it to Twilio and their engineers are currently investigating it....

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by updating twilio android sdk. thanks you everyone.